# Are the official gVim Windows binaries precompiled to work with Python 3?

Tags: python, windows, vim, windows-xp, python-3.2

I downloaded gVim73_46.exe from the official VIM.org website and installed it with its full components, and I develop using Python 3.2 (but would settle for 3.1 if it's more likely to work with VIM).

Running `vim --version` command gives me a `-python -python3` result. However, running `:echo has("python")` in Vim gives a `1` (True). Does that mean my Vim is built to support Python 2 or not?

As for Python 3, running `:py3` commands gives `E370: Could not load library python31.dll`. Does that mean it's built to support Python 3.1? If yes, can I make it use my 3.2?

If no, is there any source I can obtain precompiled Windows binaries that support Python 3 (`+python3`)?

Comment: also try `:version` within vim, does it list the same compile flags?

Comment: Yes, they are the same flags (-python -python 3). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pydave Answered your questions correctly, I can only additionally suggest using another build of vim: <s>http://tuxproject.de.nyud.net/projects/vim/</s>. It is compiled with nearly latest versions of interpreters, including Python-3.2.3. And it also uses latest vim-7.3.618 which contains my patch that extends python/python3 interpreter support (`pyeval()`/`py3eval()` functions and `vim.bindeval()`).

**Update**: it seems that it moved to http://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/, but I am no longer using precompiled binaries any longer (have a script that cross-compiles them for me) thus cannot verify this is true.

Answer (score 2):

From `:help python3`:

```
Vim can be built in four ways (:version output):
1. No Python support        (-python, -python3)
2. Python 2 support only    (+python or +python/dyn, -python3)
3. Python 3 support only    (-python, +python3 or +python3/dyn)
4. Python 2 and 3 support   (+python/dyn, +python3/dyn)

When Python 2 and Python 3 are both supported they must be loaded dynamically.
```

> running :py3 commands gives E370: Could not load library python31.dll. Does that mean it's built to support Python 3.1?

Yes. If you get python 3.1 and set your path correctly, vim should have python.

> can I make it use my 3.2?

No, vim is compiled to expect a certain interface, so you need a matching library.

Comment: +1. Thank you. Can you clarify how is Python 3 supported yet Vim gives '-python -python3'?

Comment: @MoayadMardini `has("python")==1` means that python is loaded, `+python` means that vim is compiled with python support using system linker. Vim may be compiled to rely on system linker importing Python C API functions or import them by itself using dlopen+dlsym (their windows equivalents, don’t remember names exactly). In the last case `has("python")` first tries to load python library and then reports whether python is supported, but `+python` is replaced with `+python/dyn`. Note though that on my system `vim --version` gives `+python/dyn +python3/dyn` without `-python` or `+python`.